Existence of closed volume form for closed submanifolds without boundary
Let $M$ be a smooth, oriented, compact k-dimensional submanifold without boundary of $\mathbb{R}^n$. (I will assume orientation and smoothness for the rest of the question). I am trying to establish the existence of a closed differential k-form $\omega$ such that $\int_{M} \omega  > 0$. For an abstract manifold this would be simple enough, since I could define $\omega$ directly on M, which would make it a top-form and hence trivially closed. For submanifolds of $\mathbb{R}^n$ however, I would need to define $\omega$ on something like $\mathbb{R}^n \backslash \mathbb{R}^m$ (with $m$ depending on the topology of $M$, I suppose). 
Basically, what I am trying to do is generalize the following construction:
Let $M=S^n$, $\omega = \sum_{i}^{n} (-1)^{i-1}x_{i}dx_{1}\wedge…\wedge dx_{i-1} \wedge dx_{i+1} … \wedge dx_{n}$ and $p:\mathbb{R}^n \backslash \{ 0 \} \to S^{n}$,
$x \mapsto \frac{x}{\rVert x\rVert}$. Then $p^{*}\omega$ is just the standard volume form on $S^n$, and closed. This construction itself is i think a generalisation of the well-known winding number form.
What is happening here is more than I am asking for, however: a form having positive integral on some small neighborhood and zero everywhere else would suffice.
I basically have two questions: is it possible to extend this construction to arbitrary compact hypersurfaces? I would imagine it to look something like $\det(x,v_{1},…,v_{n-1})$ divided by some mysterious function (I was thinking of using the gram-determinant, but i couldn't proceed from there).
And if so, is it possible to generalize it even further to arbitrary compacact submanifolds without boundary?
I hope this question is not too much of a conceptual muddle, thanks to anyone reading in advance. Hints or thoughts would be very much appreciated, as well as possibly helpful literature.

Did you forget to assume that $M$ is oriented?

yes of course, $M$ should be oriented, I will edit the question

You can always extend a differential form from a submanifold to the ambient manifold. This can be done for instance using a partition of unity. Try it.

I have not yet covered abstract manifolds, so differental forms on a submanifold were always defined as as forms on the ambient space, and then restricted to the submanifold in question. ...If I already had the form on the submanifold, I suppose i could pull it back by an inclusion map?

Do you know at least about partitions of unity?  Also, your question (4th sentence) makes it appear that yoy already know about abstract manifolds. Lastly, you can use the Euclidean metric to define $k$-volume forms. Think about the case $k=1, 2$ first. If you have a $k$-tuple in $R^n$, can you assign a volume to it?

The pullback by the inclusion is how you make sense of restriction to the submanifold. To extend a form, you really need a tubular neighborhood and bump functions.

yes i know about partitions of unity. I have read about abstract manifolds but i shouldn't use them, otherwise i would need to introduce the whole machinery, I should have made that clearer. I could assign a volume via the gram-determinant, no?

You don't need anything about abstract manifold. But you do need to work with local coordinates in which $M$ is "flat" inside $\Bbb R^n$, and use those coordinates to define a local extension. Be careful to use orientability to make sure these can be patched together to make something positive. ... Yes, if you have a parametrized submanifold, the Gram determinant will give you a volume form. However, you're asking only for a positive form, not necessarily the induced volume form. Oh wait. What do you mean when you say a closed $k$-form? Closed on $M$ (automatic) or closed on $\Bbb R^n$?

thanks @Ted Shifrin, i'll try it out. Is there any special trick involved in preserving closedness? I somehow cannot imagine how this would be done

As I just asked, what precisely does the question mean? The constructions I have in mind definitely do not give a closed form on $\Bbb R^n$ [and nor does yours for the sphere]. Indeed, there cannot be such a global closed form on $\Bbb R^n$; can you prove this?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Not a closed form on $\mathbb{R}^n$ of course (poincare prohibits this i think, exact forms have integral of zero in this setting), but on $\mathbb{R}^n \backslash \mathbb{R}^m$ (m=0 in my example).

You obviously need $k=n-m-1$ to have a hope. Now try your example with a torus in $\Bbb R^3$.
